# How to express the plural of "<role 1> and <role 2>"?

Tags: expressions

If someone is both a singer and a writer, I would normally say "a singer and writer". When I say "a singer and a writer", it should mean that there are two persons, one is a singer and the other is a writer.

I'm trying to figure out how to introduce two or more people, all of which are singers and writers at the same time. How should I properly express this without confusion or ambiguity? I'm finding "singers and writers" potentially meaning "some singers and some other writers" and thus ambiguous.

Comment: What do they write? If they write songs, then they're a "songwriter", and the (generally well-known) term "singer-songwriter" would be the easiest way to communicate that they both sing *and* write songs, e.g. "Alice, Bob and Charlie are all singer-songwriters." If they write other things, then obviously that doesn't work.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I could've made it clear. That could be two arbitrary roles and not necessarily related (consider *dancer* and *driver*). Then your comment suggests there's no way out. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: ***All** of these people are **singers and songwriters*** is potentially ambiguous, as you obviously realise. ***Each** of these people is **a singer and [a] songwriter*** has no such ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is that you could say "*all these people are singers and songwriters*", but this does not necessarily mean that *all* the people are *both*. For example, you could say "*all these people are mums and dads*", which would mean that collectively they were all *parents*, but obviously any individual could not be both.

So, if they are *all* both roles you would need to say "*all these people are both singers and songwriters*"

However, if you are not already aware, the term for someone who is both a singer *and* a songwriter is "[singer-songwriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singer-songwriter)".

The correct plural usage for the term *singer-songwriter* would be:

> All these people are singer-songwriters.

There is no need to use the word "both" because you are now only using one term for the dual roles.

Obviously, such a term does not exist for all such situations where dual-roles exist, but it is notable in this specific example.

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

> All of these people are both singers and songwriters  (or both dancers and drivers)

But a little ambiguity isn't always a bad thing, and it might be better to provide context instead of trying to nail down the meaning in one sentence:

> It's not easy to be a dancer when you work all day driving a truck, but these people are drivers *and* dancers.  Let's see how they manage their busy lives.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is as follows:

> Each of these people is both singer and writer.

That doesn't leave any room for ambiguity, avoiding any possible confusion or misinterpretation from the plural *all* and *are*.

You are referring to a group of *people*, but you are also using *each*, which specifically steers clear of *all*.

Since you are using *each*, you use *is* (because *each* takes a singular verb), which reinforces the singularity of the artist—and explicitly avoids *are*.

This is followed by *both singer and songwriter*. But since it's been made explicit that you're dealing with exactly one person in turn, there is still no confusion.